# Can we modify $\createdAt in an Appwrite document?

Tags: appwrite

I would like to create documents in my appwrite database, but I would like to know if when creating the document we could modify the $\createdAt?

I tried changing createdAt in data when creating my document, and I searched on other sites but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No these values cannot be changed you could maybe add an additional field but this cannot be changed not as of 05-03-2023